# In this code i still have this message when i update the data

Tags: php, mysql

I have this function and when I update the data I still have the same problem . 
I don't know where is the error. By the way my connection file is true

This is the message i put it :

> Site name Error

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Admin control</title>


</head>
<body>
</body>
<div class="head">Settings</div>



<?
/* 


CREATE TABLE `article`.`setting` (
`name_site` VARCHAR( 300 ) NOT NULL ,
`url_site` VARCHAR( 300 ) NOT NULL ,
`email_site` VARCHAR( 150 ) NOT NULL ,
`desc_site` TEXT NOT NULL ,
`kay_site` TEXT NOT NULL ,
`oepn_site` MEDIUMINT( 2 ) NOT NULL ,
`text_close_site` TEXT NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;


*/



include "../include/config.php";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$ns = $_POST['name_site'];
$us = $_POST['url_site'];
$es = $_POST['email_site'];
$ds = $_POST['desc_site'];
$ks = $_POST['kay_site'];
$os = $_POST['oepn_site'];
$ms = $_POST['text_close_site'];

}



if (@$_POST['updatesetting']){

        if(@$ns == ''){
            echo "<div class='no'> Site name Error </div>";
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=setting.php"/>';
                            exit;
                        }

            else {
                $update = mysql_query("update setting set
                        name_site='$ns',
                        url_site = '$us',
                        email_site = '$es',
                        desc_site = '$ds',
                        kay_site = '$ks',
                        oepn_site = '$os',
                        text_close_site  ='$ms'
                        ")  ;

                        if (@isset($update)){
                            echo "<div class='ok'> Update Done</div>";
                            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=setting.php"/>';
                            exit;
                        }



    }
}
$sel1 = mysql_query("select * from setting ");
$row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sel1);






$name_site = $row1['name_site'];
$url_site = $row1['url_site'];
$email_site = $row1['email_site'];
$desc_site = $row1['desc_site'];
$kay_site = $row1['kay_site'];
$oepn_site = $row1['oepn_site'];
$text_close_site = $row1['text_close_site']

?>







<div class="bodypanel">
    <form action="setting.php" method="post">
        <table width="100%" border="0" dir="rtl">
            <tr>
                <td>Site Name</td>
                <td><input type="text"  name="name_site" value="<?=$name_site;?>" ></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>Site link</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="url_site" value="<?=$url_site;?>"></td>
            </tr>




            <tr>
                <td>Email siten</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email_site" value="<?=$email_site;?>"></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>Site description</td>
                <td><textarea name="desc_site" rows="4" cols="25" > <?=$desc_site;?> </textarea></td>
            </tr>



            <tr>
                <td>Key words</td>
                <td><textarea name="kay_site" rows="4" cols="25" value="<?=$kay_site;?>"> <?=$kay_site;?> </textarea></td>
            </tr>



            <tr>
                <td>Open site</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="oepn_site" >

                        <?
                            if ($oepn_site== 1){
                                echo "<option value='1'>Open to visitor</option>
                                <option value='2'>Close to visitor</option>";
                            }
                                else {
                                    echo "<option value='2'>Close to visitor</option>
                                    <option value='1'>Open to visitor</option>";



                            }
                        ?>



                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>




            <tr>
                <td>Close message</td>
                <td><textarea name="text_close_site" rows="4" cols="25"> <?=$text_close_site;?>  </textarea></td>

            </tr>



            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="head"><input type="submit" name="updatesetting" value="save setting"> </td>

            </tr>


        </table>

    </form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, it seems that `$ns` is empty when this PHP file called. And stop silencing with `@`, it's a big no-no.

Comment: PHP also allows for short open tags <? and ?> (which are discouraged because they are only available if enabled with short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option. So either change to standard tag like <?php ?> or enable short tags from php.ini

Comment: You are doing it wrong. The logic is bad.. And the problem is here `<input type="text"  name="name_site" value="<?=$name_site;?>"`

Comment: @Foda I have submitted an answer. Is it working with that answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the checking of submission to

```
if (isset($_POST['updatesetting']))
{
     $ns = $_POST['name_site'];
     .
     .
     .
}
```